# Wordpress - Getting parent page name dynamically on parent page-specific menu item that links to child page that shares the same child page name?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Hopefully that question makes sense. This is essentially what I need:

I have a menu item that shows up on every parent page (that have different names), but will link to a child page that shares the same name. For example:

Parent Page:
http://website.com/parent-1/
Menu Item Link --> http://website.com/parent-1/overview

Parent Page:
http://website.com/parent-2/
Menu Item Link --> http://website.com/parent-2/overview

So essentially what I'm looking for is for the menu item to get the parent name dynamically when the user visits the page:
http://website.com/%parent%/overview/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's not really enough information to answer your question properly. Are you wanting to do this in PHP or Javascript or something else?

You can get the current url in javascript with

```
window.location.href
```

In php with

```
$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]
```

Specifically in wordpress

```
global $wp;
home_url( $wp->request )
```

All the answers are already out there if you search for them...

Comment: Wordpress menus. I'm looking to get the parent page dynamically in the URL when the user visits the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using the wrong tag please ask this question under Wordpress oriented tag